malloc: Unable to set up reclaim buffer (46) - disabling large cache

Reset Mac and installed  macOS 14.4.1 (23E224)
Reset iPhone 14  and installed iOS 17.5 (21F79)
Reinstalled Xcode 15.4 (15F31c)
Run a "Hello world" iOS app on a iPhone 14 real device and get:


test app(464,0x1ef1e3ec0) malloc: Unable to set up reclaim buffer (46) - disabling large cache

Any idea of the possible consequences and/or how to avoid the error?

Did you get this figured out? I am having the same issue in a new SwiftUI app using SpriteKit, literally just started working on this app and it has nothing in it except a blank scene and a SwiftUI view calling the blank scene.

Found this bit re myloc (46) "That’s unlikely to be relevant. This log entry is coming from the system memory allocator. It’s triggered because the allocator is trying to use a kernel feature that’s not supported on your system (46 is KERN_NOT_SUPPORTED). This is not uncommon with the simulator, where the simulated operating system is out of sync with the macOS kernel on which it’s running."  Apple Developer Forums

That message appears when running apps on physical iOS devices - it's just telling you that the system couldn't set up its preferred memory management method and switched to a backup strategy. Your app will work fine since iOS handles this automatically. If your app is not running try to clean builder folder and  product > run and check the logs, you will probably see the real error which doesn't let you run the app.
